# Rewrite rule does not read $_GET variable even with QSA

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue with a rewrite rule not being able to read a $_GET variable from the url, therefore not displaying user's page correctly.
This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^piqs/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^piqs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$ index.php?country=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^piqs-women/?$ index-women.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^piqs-men/?$ index-men.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^users$ users.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^users-women/?$ users-women.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^users-men/?$ users-men.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ranking$ ranking.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ranking-women/?$ ranking-women.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ranking-men/?$ ranking-men.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^newsnap$ newsnap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^edit_photo$ edit-photo.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^account$ account.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^edit_account$ edit-account.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mypage$ mypage.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mypage/follovers$ follovers.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mypage/folloving$ folloving.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^chicpiq/([0-9]+)$ snap.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA, L]
```

With this I'm trying to access the user's page from www.example.com via this link

```
<a href="<?php echo $snapusername?>">
```

This takes me to www.example.com/testuser. Testuser is the variable passed.
However when I enter this link the variable is not passed. I checked this like this:

```
if($_GET['username'] == "") {
    echo "Not working yo";
}
```

I get "Not working yo" message. I have tried adding QSA at the end of the reqrite rule, without it, without L and nothing worked.
Any ideas what might be the problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Theres no redirect defined for that case? Btw: Its followers instead of follovers, same goes for following. (typo in your rewriterule). Its pics instead of piqs aswell.

Comment: your link would need to look like `<a href="/account/?username=<?php echo $snapusername?> >Link</a>"`

Comment: @Xatenev these misspellings are intended.
@cmorrissey What if I want to avoid adding this `/account/` part? I've seens a few websites where users' accounts are redirected to www.example.com/username. That's what I would like to achieve as well.

Comment: @Xatenev  Maybe its an adult page ;) ranking-women, ranking-men .... then `piqs` would be fine :)))9

Comment: @davidb How can misspellings be intended?... Im confused. Are you trying to create some kind of super gangster code for bronx?

Comment: Dont know but must not the 'minus' escaped in the regex? dont sure, but in php its an MUST.

Comment: I tried changing the link to `<a href="?username=<?php echo $snapusername?>">` but that would try to redirect me to `http://example.com/?username=testuser` which still does not help.

Comment: @Xatenev Do you still name database fields `username` `userpassword` and the db then `user` ?? What is against it, nobody writes an URL by himself (only  hackers!), why not be cryptic? Did you ever the S3 links for Images?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I don't know what your talking about.

Comment: @Xatenev And sory but i have to do this: fol__lovers__.

Comment: @Xatenev Im taking about a free world, not about some gang....  whatever :)

Comment: @Xatenev How gives a... if i name folders *kngnbzbtnbe*, was basiclly the question.

Comment: I tried changing the link to<a href="user/<?php echo $snapusername?>"><a href="user/<?php echo $snapusername?>">` and the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` but I still cannot pass the variable.

Comment: @Xatenev Have you ever see code that was writen by spanish, italian or waht ever:) You also force evrbody to use english, im right? But you will never get what i say, i thing. I stay in the free world.

Comment: Could we refrain from off-topic? Who cares how I name my pages? Instagram isn't a proper english word and yet you have a website like this.

Comment: Test if `RewriteBase /` is missing, and sry for the disco here;)

Comment: Ok, I got this! It was a really stupid mistake, most likely done because I'd been copying/pasting other rewrite rules. All I had to do is to change `profile.php?id=$1 [QSA, L]` to `profile.php?username=$1 [QSA, L]` as username is the variable I was looking for. I'm sorry for all the trouble and thank you for your fervent comments.